# C-Preprocessor: Combine chars into a string

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a list of character definitions, like this:

```
#define MYCHAR_1 0xC3
#define MYCHAR_2 0xB6
```

(These are the two bytes that form the UTF-8 character "ö")

Is it possible to create a macro that takes the prefix (in this example "MYCHAR") and yields the string "\xC3\xB6"? (i.e. "ö")

In other words can the C-preprocessor create a static string (or array) out of static array-elements?

The end result should be usable by a function that has a string as parameter, for example:

```
printf(MY_MAGIC_MACRO(MYCHAR));
```

should print "ö".

Comment: You *could* of course do `char ouml[] = { MYCHAR_1, MYCHAR_2, 0 };`

Comment: OK, but how can I use that in a function? - I added a clarification to the question. (BTW, you would need unsigned for UTF-8 characters)

Comment: You don't have to use `unsigned char` for UTF-8 characters; either `signed char` or plain `char` is also correct, usable, etc.  However, in all respects except standard library support, `unsigned char` will be easier than a possibly (or definitely) signed `char` representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With numeric definitions as shown, it is moderately hard.  However, assuming you have a C99 or later compiler, you can use a compound literal:

```
#define MYCHAR_1 0xC3
#define MYCHAR_2 0xB6

printf("%s", (char []){ MYCHAR_1, MYCHAR_2, '\0' });
```

If you're stuck with C89, then you probably don't have any good options other than to define an array variable and pass that to the function.

If you want a MY_MAGIC_MACRO(MYCHAR) to work, then you have to know how many names there are (2 per prefix in this example):

```
#define MY_MAGIC_MACRO(x) ((char []){ x##_1, x##_2, '\0' })

printf("%s\n", MY_MAGIC_MACRO(MYCHAR));
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYCHAR_1 0xC3
#define MYCHAR_2 0xB6

#define MY_MAGIC_MACRO(x) ((char []){ x##_1, x##_2, '\0' })

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", (char[]){ MYCHAR_1, MYCHAR_2, '\0' });
    printf("%s\n", MY_MAGIC_MACRO(MYCHAR));
    return 0;
}
```

The output on a UTF-8 terminal is `ö` twice on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you want to achieve that I can come up with:

```
#define MYCHAR_1 "\xC3"
#define MYCHAR_2 "\xB6"

const char STR [] = "ABC" MYCHAR_1 "DEF" MYCHAR_2;
```